# How to update imports and icons name from heroIcons v1 to v2 automatically?

Tags: reactjs, heroicons

I tried to update the heroicons from v1 to v2 in my project (react), which uses a lot of heroicons taken from heroicons v1. But now with the update to v2, heroicons changed lots of imports and file names. Doing it manually is a hustle. Is there a way to do it automatically with the update of the package so I do not have to change icons name and imports ?